# Diabetes patient record data sets?

Tags: data-request, medical, machine-learning

Are there any data sets of diabetes patient records? Logs of blood sugars, carbohydrate, activity etc plus other stats like age, height, weight.

Comment: You might be able to find a paper in PubMed that uses that type of data, and then contact the author to see about getting the (anonymized) data.

Answer (score 7):

Your question is so general it's hard to be sure I'm answering it correctly. More detail would be quite helpful. Here's a stab, though:

If you're looking for datasets that are already open and are fairly standard social science data, I would look at what [ICPSR](http://www.icpsr.umich.edu/icpsrweb/ICPSR/studies?q=diabetes&searchSource=icpsr-landing) holds. They have several datasets, in particular [this one](http://www.icpsr.umich.edu/icpsrweb/ICPSR/studies/34974?q=diabetes&searchSource=icpsr-landing), contributed by Jens Ludwig at UChicago.

However, none of the files they have probably match what it sounds like you're looking for: in-depth logs from monitoring devices. On that I don't know of any data that's available, at all; to my knowledge, monitoring devices (at least in the US) don't tend to be wired at all.

Comment: The data you've shared is helpful and interesting, I'm not just looking for monitoring device data. More detail in the question would be limiting.

Answer (score 6):

Here is [CGM data from a 14 year-old Type I diabetic](http://figshare.com/articles/Continuos_Glucose_Monitor_Data/741296).

Data Includes Datetime Stamp, ISIG, and Glucose level.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Quick search for "CGM" on figshare.com resulted in several more interesting documents.

Answer (score 3):

There is a canonical diabetes data set that is used for all sorts of machine learning tutorials. You can check it out [here](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Diabetes).

> Diabetes patient records were obtained from two sources: an automatic electronic recording device and paper records.

In general, the [parent link from UCI](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets.html) has great data sets that are time tested and very useful for learning techniques in machine learning.

If you are using Python, the [scikit-learn library](http://scipy-lectures.github.io/advanced/scikit-learn/) offers a machine learning [tutorial](http://scipy-lectures.github.io/advanced/scikit-learn/#linear-model-from-regression-to-sparsity) that includes a diabetes data set, among other things.